# No me permite acceder a un array en el index 0 - Angular 9

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema para poder acceder a la posición 0 de un array, estoy usando Angular 9.

Tengo el siguiente código de un componente para dirigirme hacia un Dialog donde ocurre toda la lógica y es aquí donde mando al array:

```js
lst_materiales = []

    ordenMaterialPorTrabajo(ot_id,trabajo_id,item_lesson,trabajador) {
      this.lst_materiales = []
    // console.log(`OT_ID: ${ot_id} y TRABAJO_ID: ${trabajo_id}`)
    // debugger
    this.mantenimientoservice.getOrdenMaterialesByTrabajo(ot_id,trabajo_id)
      .subscribe((data:any) => {
        this.lst_materiales.push(data); 
       })

     const dialogRef = this.utils.saveUpdateOrdenMaterialesDialog( 
       "Save-Update-Materiales", 
       ot_id,
       trabajo_id,
       trabajador,
       this.lst_materiales
     ); 

  }
```

Al Dialog (otro componente) llega el array de forma correcta, lo puedo comprobar con un `console.log` en el siguiente pedazo de código:

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data.ot_id, this.data.trabajo_id, this.data.trabajador); 
    console.log(this.data.dataObj) // Aquí lo compruebo
    this.setOrdenMaterialDefault(this.data.dataObj); // Aquí mando 
    this.createForm();     
  }
```

Lo que me retorna en la consola es un array con todos los elementos que requiero, pero en la posición 0 y cuando trato de hacer un `forEach` a ese array es donde me tira todos los errores siguientes:

[image: Consola]

Luego hago el `forEach` a la posición 0 del array:

```js
setOrdenMaterialDefault(obj) {
    obj[0].forEach(item => this.addMaterial(item))
  }
```

Y el error final es que no puede recorrer un `undefined`:

[image: Error]

Por si le sirve de algo, también dejaré el código de mi servicio:

```js
saveUpdateOrdenMaterialesDialog(title,ot_id,trabajo_id,trabajador, dataObj) {
    return this.dialog.open(SaveUpdateOrdenMaterialesComponent, {
      data: { title, ot_id, trabajo_id, trabajador, dataObj},
      width: '1500px',
      disableClose: true
    });
  }
```

Comment: El error lo deja bien claro: no tienes un array, tienes un `undefined`. Y eso a su vez está causado porque `obj` es un array vacío

Comment: Pero puedo visualizar que ese Array me retorna dentro en el index 0 la suma de 2 objetos, cómo podría acceder a ellos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema de asincronía, los datos del arreglo están disponibles hasta que se ejecuta el callback del `subscribe`. Se puede corregir abriendo el modal dentro de la función callback:

```
ordenMaterialPorTrabajo(ot_id, trabajo_id, item_lesson, trabajador) {
    this.lst_materiales = []
    this.mantenimientoservice.getOrdenMaterialesByTrabajo(ot_id, trabajo_id)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.lst_materiales.push(data);
            const dialogRef = this.utils.saveUpdateOrdenMaterialesDialog(
                "Save-Update-Materiales",
                ot_id,
                trabajo_id,
                trabajador,
                this.lst_materiales
            );
        })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo resolvió. Una consulta, ¿alguna forma de trabajar con async/await esta parte?

Comment: async/await es "azúcar sintáctico" para manejar promesas, angular trabaja con observables, lo que complica el uso de async/await (no es imposible, pero no es aconsejable)

Comment: Comprendo, gracias nuevamente por la ayuda :'D

Answer (score 1):

La consola del navegador te está confundiendo:

[image: Consola]

Si te fijas, la primera línea muestra `[]`. Es decir, es un array vacío. Eso indica que cuando muestras el array en la consola, no tiene elementos.

Cuando haces click sobre el elemento, el navegador te muestra el valor actual, en el que ya se le han añadido dos elementos.

Puedes reproducir el escenario así: [Ejemplo](https://i.imgur.com/lBPnCGI.mp4)

Por tanto el problema es que `this.data.dataObj` es un array vacío

Si quieres ver el valor real del array en el momento de usar console.log, usa

```
console.log(this.data.dataObj.toString());
```